# how to add multiple linear lines for a flutter graph

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a linear graph using the below code. I use **charts flutter package**.. the first image shows the graph I created. the second image shows what I need to be implemented   I want to add another two lines for the same graph with different data values. how can I do this? appreciate your help on this. I use hardcoded values for the graph.

[image]

[image]

> developer_series.dart

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;


class DeveloperSeries {
  final int day;
  final int calories;
  final charts.Color barColor;

  DeveloperSeries(
      {
        required this.day,
        required this.calories,
        required this.barColor
      }
      );
}
```

> developer_chart.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'developer_series.dart';


class DeveloperChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<DeveloperSeries> data;

  DeveloperChart({required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<charts.Series<DeveloperSeries,int>> series = [
      charts.Series(
          id: "calories",
          data: data,
          domainFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.day,
          measureFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.calories,
          colorFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.barColor
      )
    ];

    return Container(
      height: 700,
     // padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
     //  decoration: BoxDecoration(
     //    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
     //
     //  ),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only( top: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(125, 158, 205, 1.0),
                            Color.fromRGBO(158, 125, 243, 0.7490196078431373),
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          end: Alignment.centerRight,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: TextButton(onPressed:() {},

                        child: const Text('Daily', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(125, 158, 205, 1.0),
                            Color.fromRGBO(158, 125, 243, 0.7490196078431373),
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          end: Alignment.centerRight,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: TextButton(onPressed:() {},

                        child: const Text('Week', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(125, 158, 205, 1.0),
                            Color.fromRGBO(158, 125, 243, 0.7490196078431373),
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          end: Alignment.centerRight,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: TextButton(

                        onPressed:() {},

                        child: const Text('Month', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),


              Expanded(
                child: charts.LineChart(series,
                  animate: true,
                    domainAxis: const charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                      renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
                          labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: charts.MaterialPalette.white,
                          ),
                          lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                            color: charts.MaterialPalette.transparent,
                          )),
                      tickProviderSpec:
                      charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false),
                     // viewport: charts.NumericExtents(2016.0, 2022.0),
                    ),

                  primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(

                      renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
                         // labelOffsetFromAxisPx: -20,
                         // labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.after,
                          lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                            color: charts.MaterialPalette.white,
                            thickness: 1,
                          )
                      ),

                  ),


                   ),
              ),


            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> graph_calories.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'developer_chart.dart';
import 'developer_series.dart';

class GraphDisplayCalories extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<GraphDisplayCalories> createState() => _GraphDisplayCaloriesState();
}

class _GraphDisplayCaloriesState extends State<GraphDisplayCalories> {
  final List<DeveloperSeries> data = [

    DeveloperSeries(   
      day: 2017,
      calories: 40000,
      barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.purple),
    ),
    DeveloperSeries(
      day: 2018,
      calories: 10000,
      barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.purple),
    ),
    DeveloperSeries(
      day:2019,
      calories: 20000,
      barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.purple),
    ),
    DeveloperSeries(
      day: 2020,
      calories: 35000,
      barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.purple),
    ),
    DeveloperSeries(
      day: 2021,
      calories: 20000,
      barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.purple),

    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Center(
          child: DeveloperChart(
            data: data,
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add multiple 'series'. See https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/dash_pattern